# What does the capital -N option in an if statement mean?

Tags: bash, test

```
man test
```

only explains what `-n` means, wit a lowercase n.

How does the capital -N work in this script?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check for an altered certificate (means there was a renew)
if [[ -N '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mx1.example.com/fullchain.pem' ]]; then  
   # Reload postfix
   /bin/systemctl reload postfix
   # Restart dovecot
   /bin/systemctl restart dovecot
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-N` (for `N`ew) option was added to zsh's conditional expressions in version 3.0.1 in 1996 to support the new `checkmail` autoloadable function which can be used to check if you have any new mail in any or your mailboxes (`$MAIL`, `$mailpath`...)

It does that by checking whether the file's modification time is newer than its last access time, in other word that it hasn't been read since the last time it was modified (since you received email when applied to a mailbox file).

From the [`Changelog` file from that time](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Etc/ChangeLog-3.0):

```
Sun Aug 25 23:06:43 1996  Zoltán Hidvégi  <hzoli@cs.elte.hu>

        * Functions/checkmail, Doc/zsh.texi, Doc/zshmisc.man, Src/cond.c,
          Src/parse.c: new -N contitional test to check if the access time
          of a file is not newer than its modification time.  A new
          checkmail function is also included to check mailpath or the
          given forlers for new mails.
```

Interestingly, that `checkmail` function was never documented (it's still included in `zsh`, you can still do `autoload checkmail; checkmail`), and the functionality (to check for new email before each prompt) was already built in the shell anyway like it was in the Korn shell already in the 80s. The next year, the new `stat` builtin introduced in 3.1.2 would also have made that `-N` test unnecessary as the `mtime > atime` check could have then been done manually, so it's quite lucky that flag exists at all.

That `test -N` was nevertheless later copied by `bash` (2.02 in 1998), ksh93 (ksh93o in 2003) and `yash` (2.22 in 2010).

It's not so useful these days where a lot of systems choose not to update the access timestamp of files any longer for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Bash conditional expression, not a general `test` conditional expression. [It means](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)

> **-N** *file*
>
> True if *file* exists and has been modified since it was last read.

`-N` is true if the file’s modification time is newer than its access time.